# SQL query to find the previous date, current date and next date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, select

If the current date is 3/12/2015, then I need to get the files from dates 2/12/2015, 3/12/2015, 4/12/2015. Can anyone tell me an idea for how to do it?

```
<%
try
{
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");


Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/CubeHomeTrans","sa","softex");

Statement statement = con.createStatement() ; 

ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("

select file from tablename
where date >= DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE()))
and date <= DATEADD(day, +1, convert(date, GETDATE()))") ;


while(resultset.next())
{
String datee =resultset.getString("Date");
out.println(datee);
}
}
catch(SQLException ex){
System.out.println("exception--"+ex);

}

%>
```

This is the query I have done, but it's erroneous. I need to get the previous date, current date and next date.

Comment: Hace you try add an order by date -1 day

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**DATE_ADD()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) And [**DATE_SUB()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) functions:

Try this:

```
SELECT FILE, DATE
FROM ForgeRock
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(DATE, '%d/%m/%Y') >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  AND STR_TO_DATE(DATE, '%d/%m/%Y') <= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe53d5/3)

**::OUTPUT::**

```
| file |       DATE |
|------|------------|
|  dda | 31/12/2015 |
|  ass | 01/01/2016 |
|  sde | 02/01/2016 |
```

Comment: is these query help to find the files of yesterday and tomorrow?? i need to get the files of current date too

Comment: @halfe The above query will give you the data of 1 day prior to `DATE` column, 'Date` column and 1 day after of `DATE` column. If `Date` column id today's date then above query will return today, yesterday and tomorrow's data

Comment: can u please tell me how to add that in SELECT FILE 
FROM tablename
WHERE DATE >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  AND DATE <= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);

Comment: @halfe What do you want to do?

Comment: the query should return the files on current date,previous day of current date and next day of current date

Comment: @halfe Please add your table structure so that I can explain you

Comment: CREATE TABLE ForgeRock
 (`id` int,'file' string, `date` varchar(20))
;
 
INSERT INTO ForgeRock
 (`id`,'file', `date`)
VALUES
    (0,dda,'31/12/2015'),
 (1, ass,'01/01/2016' ),
 (2, sde,'02/01/2016' ),
 (3,gff ,'03/01/2016'),
    (4, sfd,'04/01/2016'),
    (5, abc ,'05/01/2016')
;

Comment: i am using ms sql when i run the query i got an exception exception--com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CURRENT_DATE'.   can it be solved?

Comment: @halfe For SQL Server the functions are different so you have to change those functions in your query

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way to get all these **dates** are as below:-

**CURRENT DATE**

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

**NEXT DAY DATE** *(Adding 1 to the `dateadd` parameter for one day ahead)*

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 1)
```

**YESTERDAY DATE** *(Removing 1 from the `datediff` parameter for one day back)*

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 1, GETDATE()), 0)
```

If you go through the link [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1426/how-to-the-get-current-date-without-the-time-part), you will get an amazing way of explanation for getting `date`. It will clear your logic and will be useful for future reference too.

Hope that helps you

Answer (score 1):

You can use dateAdd function

syntax

```
DATEADD(datepart,number,date)
```

i.e for current date

```
select GETDATE()
```

for yesterday

```
select DATEADD(D,-1,GETDATE())
```

for tomorrow

```
select DATEADD(D,1,GETDATE())
```

so, your query should be like

```
select file from tablename
where date >= DATEADD(D,-1,GETDATE())
and date <= DATEADD(D,1,GETDATE())
```

Comment: is these query help to find the files of yesterday and tomorrow?? i need to get the files of current date too

Comment: yes. where condition is checking yesterday's to tomorrow's date. i.e yesterday, today and tomorrow .

Answer (score 0):

current date

```
date = (SELECT CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126))
```

yesterday

```
date = (SELECT dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0))
```

next day

```
date= SELECT DATEADD(day, 1,(convert(date, GETDATE())))
```

Comment: your last query for `next day` wont run in `SQL server 2005` because `Date` doesn't work in `2005` you can use `datetime` in place of `date` for that. Rest all is working fine. Also, you need to mention what is `date = (.....`